# Pré-processadores de CSS - Vantagens e Desvantagens

Tags: css

vocês usam Pré-processadores de CSS, se sim, quais??

Quais suas vantagens e desvantagens??

Por que usam? Ou Por que não usam??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Meio ampla essa pergunta..

Comment: https://rogertakemiya.com.br/pre-processadores-de-css/